# borderWidth : "transparent" , React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, expo, react-native-stylesheet

i dont know why but for some reason when im applying border width style as "transparent" my expo app crashes immediately

```
<Pressable
style = {{borderWidth:"transparent"}}
>
...some components
</Pressable>
```

Im using react native expo and experienced this bug in android , it might not crash in an ios device i guess.

i wanted to add this style on some condition

```
borderWidth: lookingOptions.includes(item?.name) ? "transparent" : 0.7,
```

but just gave up as i thought it isnt possible , atleast in android , i dont know if its a react native bug or expo bug .

Comment: borderWidth cannot be transparent since it is not a color, try `borderWidth: 0` or `borderColor: 'transparent'`

Comment: i see , i was following a youtube tutorial where the guy did the same thing and his code was still working ,  i dont know why this made the app crash instead of throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

The borderWidth property in React Native expects a numeric value representing the width of the border in logical pixels.

Please use this line for styling

```
borderWidth: lookingOptions.includes(item?.name) ? 0 : 0.7,
```

Instead of "transparent" use 0.